# Samson GT Studio Monitors

Tags: studio, monitors

Hi all,

Just wondering if anyone has had any experiences with the Samson GT Studio monitors. I have heard some good things about them and there are some interesting reports out there regarding their performance. But I thought it would be interesting to hear what you SSD's had to say as well.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 2):

ok, after reading small reviews, and also looking at the tech specs at samson webpage, i don't think that its a good monitoring system, and also, i don't think that is a good all in one system, basically you got active monitors(with amplifiers inside), also you got cheap 16-bit 44.1kHz/48kHz interface with phantom power...this means it should sound noisy, and knowing overall samson monitors, these shouldn't be better than any of the other samson studio monitors(all of they'r monitors are quite...bad).

also other thing that there aren't actually good monitors at this price range... you can take one krk monitor that cost a little bit less,but that isn't actually that great too.

anyway if your budget is small, i think you should go and just listen to them and decide it for yourself, who knows maybe samson did a great job creating these ;)